# How to go to the particular Tab of TabBarController from the end of PageViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I am working on app with Tab Bar controller with 4 tabs, the first tab goes to page view controller where I have 9 questions on 9 pages using scroll transition style. From the 9th page I want to go to the 2nd Tab of my Tab Bar Controller. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `self.tabBarController` is your UITabBarController:

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

Or use:

```
[self.navigationController.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

Comment: I put this line in viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *) method but it gave the error because of "incompatible result type UIViewController". do you know what is the best place to put that line ?

Comment: In that method, you specify which UIViewController should be shown after scrolling back or forward, so don't put this call over there. I don't know how you implemented the 9th page, but I assume that there's some user interaction required, i.e. pressing a button, to exit the UIPageViewController. At that point, call the "setSelectedIndex" method above. Use "self.navigationController.tabBarController" for that.